# Turbo C++ 3.0 not working on my laptop

Tags: graphics, turbo-c++

I have a Dell laptop and Windows 8.1 is installed on it. I want to run Turbo C++ on my laptop (x64 build) for graphics programming .I am unable to install it maybe some feature is turned off in my system but i dont know which features. And I have tried all the versions of Turbo C++.

Kindly suggest some other platform which have graphics library as i have tried c-free also but it does not have graphics lib.

Comment: It is a stone cold old 16-bit program.  Your 64-bit operating system can no longer run them.  You need to use a DOS emulator.  Or just not bother, there is absolutely no reason to get stuck on a 24 year old C++ compiler with excellent modern ones available for free.

Comment: also same setup of turbo c++ is working on my friend's laptop which has same config as mine. could you think of any feature which might be off on my system preventing turbo c++ from running ??

Comment: 1. install `DOSbox` or `Virtual PC + MS-DOS`... DOSbox can be configured to launch the Turbo C++ IDE automatically 2. Sadly on some schools is TC still used even nowadays ... (don't get me wrong in its time it was superb compiler but now there are much better compilers out there even from Borland/Embarcadero). 3. what is more alarming on many schools they are still programing mostly text mode commandline apps anyway. 4. Microsoft adds just WoW64 which is capable running 32bit Apps .. All the 16bit legacy software is usseles without emulation now ...

Answer (score 0):

try eclipse IDE with GNU C/C++ compiler bundled or NetBeans with GNU C/C++ bundled or even try Dev C++

Comment: i tried working on dev c++ but its not working even after downloading graphics.h it says that its not compatible with 64 bit versions.

Comment: also same setup of turbo c++ is working on my friend's laptop which has same config as mine. could you think of any feature which might be off on my system preventing turbo c++ from running ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an emulator to work with Turbo C++ in windows laptop 64 bit. 
You can use DosBox, last time I tried with 0.74 and it still works fine with my laptop.

Reference: http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Turbo_CPP/Step_by_Step.html